# What is stored in the keyboardbuffer and in which format?

Tags: keyboard, character, buffer, keycode, scancodes

I am new to keyboards so please excuse my question. I know that

- a keypress on the keyboard produces a scancode
- a scancode is used to obtain a virtual key (dependant on the kbdxx.dll)
- the virtual key + modifier key are used to get the character.

I also know that there is the keyboardbuffer. Now my question:

**Inside the buffer, what is stored there** - the scancode?, the keycode? or the character?

And if the character is stored **in what format** ( as a character, the Unicode-number,...?)